# ArcMap crashes on my PC

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

My ArcMap app crashes after opening ArcTool box. Any ideas what might cause this problem and the solution please.

Comment: What version, OS, other software etc do you have? Anything else that might influence this behaviour that we need to know about? Please use the edit button to update your question.

Comment: Also include whether it has ever worked (and if so, the conditions under which it stopped working), and whether it works for others.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:
Close all instances of ArcGIS / ArcCatalog.

Rename the ESRI folder here:
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\ESRI

call it ESRI_Old

Rename the ArcGIS folder here:
C:\Users\%username%\Documents\ArcGIS

call it ArcGIS_Old

Now see if it works.
When you re-start Arc, it will create a new "ESRI" folder and a new "ArcGIS" folder.  If it hasn't worked, you can delete these newly created folders and re-name the ones with "_Old" at the end of their names to restore them.